# An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security. on IE9

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a Form on a page which is getting populated by POST parameters. Suppose, if i send `ID` through `POST` request and all fields are getting populated based on that ID from Database.

When i refresh page then it asks me permission like as below

[image]

and this operation works fine in all Browsers except IE. when i press Retry in **IE9** then i am getting

> Not Acceptable!
>   
> An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be 
>   found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.

I read somewhere to solve this problem as below

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
# Turn off mod_security filtering.  SMF is a big boy, it does not need its hands held.
SecFilterEngine Off

# The below probably isn't needed, but better safe than sorry.
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

But this does not seem to work either.